# SQL Syntax in MS Access Form

Tags: sql, parameters

I have a problem of SQL syntax which I have been struggling for days.

I have created an MS Access 2010 Form called `IP Country Form` into which I want to insert into a TextBox called `Country` the Country obtained from the following query which queries a table called `IPLocation` which contains the Countries according to IP Numbers with the fields:

```
IPNS IPNE CY2(2 letter Country Code) CY3(3 Letter country Code) Country (full Country Name)
```

The table rows looks like this:

```
IPNS     | IPNE     | CY2 | CY3 | COUNTRY
19791872 | 19922943 | TH  | THA | THAILAND
```

The form calculates the IP Number from the IP address and places it in a TextBox called `IPNumber`, which I then use in an SQL Query to obtained the Country which corresponds to it.

My current query is:

```
SELECT IPLocation.IPNS, IPLocation.IPNE, IPLocation.CY2, IPLocationCY3, IP.Location.Country 
  FROM IPLocation 
 WHERE (((IPLocation.IPNS)<" & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber]) 
   And ((IPLocation.IPNE) > " & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber]))
```

IPNS, IPNE are Numbers as is IPNumber

Essentially the query is designed to find the Country where the IPNumber lies between IPNS and IPNE.

Any help would be much appreciated.

A test query I use:

```
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("
                 SELECT IPLocation.IPNS, IPLocation.IPNE, IPLocation.CY2, IPLocation.CY3,
                        IPLocation.Country 
                   FROM IPLocation 
                  WHERE (((IPLocation.IPNS)>19791871) 
                    AND ((IPLocation.IPNE)<19922944))
           ")
```

Works fine and returns the correct country

Comment: Your < and > are reversed in you test Query.

Answer (score 0):

On the query you use on your code you have the comparison operators reversed on the `AND` clause.

`IPLocation.IPNS)` **>** `" & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber]`

`IPLocation.IPNE)` **<** `" & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber]`

Should be:

```
SELECT IPLocation.IPNS, IPLocation.IPNE, IPLocation.CY2, IPLocationCY3,
       IP.Location.Country 
  FROM IPLocation 
 WHERE (((IPLocation.IPNS) > " & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber]) 
   And ((IPLocation.IPNE) < " & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber]))
```

Comment: Hi All, My problem is when I run the query within a Procedure using the statement: Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT CY2, CY3, Country FROM IPLocation WHERE IPNS <" & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber] And IPNE > " & [Forms]![IP Country Form]![IPNumber]"). Compile Error variable IPNE is not defined.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the error and any new information you can provide. As you can see, code on comments does not work well.